# Solana get transaction info

Tags: transactions

When i approve my transaction from Fantom or SolFlare, those wallet can display amount sol or token I transfer. I want to know how they can do this. Please help

Answer (score 1):

Using an RPC endpoint, call `getSignaturesForAddress`
https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#getsignaturesforaddress

Then follow that up with a `getTransaction` call for each signature (these can be batched)
https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#gettransaction

This will give you all the info you need on which assets moved where. There are services with APIs that make this more straightforward like Helius.